# No route found for "GET /assets/css/..."

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

I migrated a Symfony 2 website to a shared hosting which uses CPanel. After solving many issues, I'm stumped on this one. It seems that Symfony cannot find the resources in the assets directory (web/assets).

I opened the log and found a bunch of errors like the one in the title. I tried clearing the cache and setting usecontroller = true in config.yml. Any suggestion?

**Update**: Here's a sample error line:

> [2015-10-04 03:19:58] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /assets/css/pgwslider.css"" at /home/afianzar/public_html/htdocs/app/cache/prod/classes.php line 1883 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for \"GET /assets/css/pgwslider.css\" at /home/afianzar/public_html/htdocs/app/cache/prod/classes.php:1883, Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException:  at /home/afianzar/public_html/htdocs/app/cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php:994)"} []

**Update 2**: In base.html.twig, here's how pgwslider.css is included:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/pgwslider.css" />
```

Comment: What are the URLs that symfony is using to find (and failing to find) the assets?

Comment: I updated the post with that information

Comment: How did you include `pgwslider.css` in your template?

Comment: If the files are there (`web/assest/*`) and they have proper permissions, one thing can be wrong: webserver config which not serve the file if file exists.

Comment: @Federico: I added that info in the post

Comment: @malcolm: In the server, the files are in public_html/htdocs/web/assets. Since the messages go directly to the assets dir, I wonder if they consider the web dir as the base or not. They all have 0755 permissions, I guess that should be enough. About webserver config, I'm quite inexperienced on that... you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: @dario_ramos - I don't know which webserver you have, but first rule for access your files should be something like: `if file exist return file` and later if file doesn't exist, the webserver perform other rewriting rules. I think there is the problem, in .htaccess config (if you use Apache), or maybe hosting provider blocking some rules...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that the css - file is in the `public` folder of the bundle where it's used. Then check if it is installed (copy in Web folder or as symlink - via `php bin/console assets:install --symlink`)
Then inside your twig file use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset(path to css file) }} ">
```

If the site is already online make sure to delete cached twig files inside `app/cache/prod/`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still pretty new to Symfony and didn't quite follow that. I dont' know which bundle is using the css file; as far as I can tell only `base.html.twig` is using it. But I might be wrong. How can I tell?

Comment: I assume that most twig files inside the project extend `base.html.twig`. So you can insert this line inside the head of this file. In the end it will look as follows: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('web/bundles/nameOfYourBundle/css/assetName.css') }}">`